# Formatters for deep nested XML node serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I need to serialize my C# class to XML looking something like so:

```
<request>
    <session>12345</session>
    <page>1</page>
    <elements_per_page>999</elements_per_page>
    <location>
       <zone>aaaa</zone>
       <region>bbbb</region>
       <coordinates>
           <lat>38.680632</lat>
           <lon>-96.5001</lon>
       </coordinates>
    </location>
</request>
```

What I don't want is 3 classes (request, location, coordinates), I just want 1 class with all changable attributes as root of that class and then added some serialization tags that would create that nested XML, is that at all possible?

Let's start with the bare class:

```
[XmlRoot]
class request
{
    [XmlElement]
    public int session { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public int page { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public int elements_per_page { get; set; }
    [?]
    public string zone { get; set; }
    [?]
    public string region { get; set; }
    [?]
    public decimal lat { get; set; }
    [?]
    public decimal lon { get; set; }
}
```

How do I map them so the XML like I described is created? Thanks for your help good people :)

Answer (score 0):

> "is that at all possible?"

No. What's the problem of having 3 classes? How would you want to make a XML-to-static-code linking at all in some other way?

Moreover, if you just want to dirtly spit out some XML, you could use, for example, `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and build an xml from scratch which you could serialize with `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`. Like this:

```
public string SerializeRequest(Request request)
{
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

        XmlElement requestElement = document.CreateElement("request");

        XmlElement sessionElement = document.CreateElement("session");
        sessionElement.InnerText = request.session.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        XmlElement pageElement = document.CreateElement("page");
        pageElement.InnerText = request.page.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        XmlElement elementsPerPageElement = document.CreateElement("elements_per_page");
        elementsPerPageElement.InnerText = request.elements_per_page.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        XmlElement zoneElement = document.CreateElement("zone");
        zoneElement.InnerText = request.zone;
        XmlElement regionElement = document.CreateElement("region");
        regionElement.InnerText = request.region;

        XmlElement latElement = document.CreateElement("lat");
        latElement.InnerText = request.lat.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        XmlElement lonElement = document.CreateElement("lon");
        lonElement.InnerText = request.lon.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        XmlElement coordinatesElement = document.CreateElement("coordinate");
        coordinatesElement.AppendChild(latElement);
        coordinatesElement.AppendChild(lonElement);

        XmlElement locationElement = document.CreateElement("location");
        locationElement.AppendChild(zoneElement);
        locationElement.AppendChild(regionElement);
        locationElement.AppendChild(coordinatesElement);

        requestElement.AppendChild(sessionElement);
        requestElement.AppendChild(pageElement);
        requestElement.AppendChild(elementsPerPageElement);
        requestElement.AppendChild(locationElement);

        document.AppendChild(requestElement);

        string serializedObj = document.OuterXml;
        return serializedObj;
}
```

Comment: 1. I don't want to "dirty spit out" any XML, I need to generate XML according to a specification provided to me (I didn't get XSD to generate classes).
2. What is the point of having 3 classes? I was hoping there are some formatters to point out this is nested like that...